# Counting ways of not sitting in adjacent seats

Tags: combinatorics

> $5$ people $A,B,C,D,E$ sit on a bench.
>
> In how many way they can sit that $B$ and $C$ do not sit together?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Do all permutations for all 5 people, and then subtract the ones where B and C do sit together

Comment: I suggest to use permutations.

Comment: @mlc Right. :) Thanks!